# htaccess: Wamp server redirecting uncorrectly to localhost

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, wamp

I created a htaccess file in **localhost/monSite/Web/**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^admin/ bootstrap.php?app=Backend [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ bootstrap.php?app=Frontend [QSA,L]
```

When I am in a page on **localhost/monSite/Web/**
and I press a link

```
<a href="/">login</a>
```

I want it to redirect to **localhost/monSite/Web/**

The problem I have is that it redirects to **localhost**